# how to create a drain pan wall?

Tags: water-heater, washing-machine, patching-drywall, putty

I did not know about drain pans with detachable fronts ([https://www.amazon.com/Square-Water-Heater-Detachable-Front/dp/B07TKDWNW7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TKDWNW7)), and so ended up hacking one myself.

[image: drain pan]

My question now is: how do I create a "wall" near the parts that I broke off? I am thinking of something that can be molded and that hardens after some time. It also needs to be water proof.

Not sure if wall putty would work. Any better suggestions?

Comment: Now that you know about drain pans with detachable fronts, why not buy a drain pan with a detachable front? PVC trim tends to be thin and flexible. Vinyl molding material could work.

Comment: Thanks! Vinyl molding is a good idea. What do you recommend for sealing it to the plastic pan?

Comment: Most bathroom sealants will say that they're not for below water. I assume this pan is typically empty, so I would use a bathroom sealant anyway. Silicone. I might use bolts every 3" or 4" to hold things tight.